# Magento 2 (magento 2.2.1) New Custom Language Pack How To Install( Eg : Tamil )

Tags: custom, magento2.2, installation, language

When i create my new custom language pack completely but it showing error when i install

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ta_IN
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing mode and running command

Comment: Find below reference link this will helpful for you,
[Referal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.1 is differ from folder structure

Here i found why the package not install ?

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy **ta_IN** package not listed in language so showing that error 
while we install new language included **(lib/internal/Magento/Framework)**

so we add in the file 
[image]

then u run to install your custom language

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ta_IN -f

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command for static content deploy without changing mode:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ta_IN -f
```

I Hope it will work for you.